# Can't control readonly property in a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, readonly

I am using a datagridview in a C# application. And I need that only one specific column be editable, but not the whole column. The last row must be readonly.

I set datagridview readonly property, at design, as false. Then I used the sequence of codes to turn all other columns as readonly:

`dataGridView1.Columns["Col1"].ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.Columns["Col2"].ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.Columns["Col3"].ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.Columns["Col4"].ReadOnly = true;`

The datagridview has 5 columns. At this point, only the Col5 is editable. But I need the last row to be readonly, so I tried:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].ReadOnly = true;
```

That didn't work, the whole Col5 is still editable. So I tried:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["Col5"].ReadOnly = true;
```

That didn't work as well. The whole Col5 was still editable.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 2):

### Method 1:

You can change the row's (or cell's) read-only state after the data binding is completed:

```
dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete += dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete;
```

And,

```
void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].ReadOnly = true;
}
```

### Method 2:

You can cancel the edit of any cell if row is the last row:

```
dataGridView1.CellBeginEdit += dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit;
```

And;

```
void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = e.RowIndex == dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
}
```

Comment: Was stuck for a while with the same problem, adding my ReadOnly set code into the DataBindingComplete event worked! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the datagridview.readonly property in design as true. Last column readonly false. And after that last row as readonly true.